# Symfony how to create reusable widget with PHP and twig

Tags: symfony, widget

Let's say I have comments in more than one spot in website. How can I create something like 
{{ render_widget('comments', {"object": object} ) }} ? That would render the form and list with all comments for that object ?

Comment: Maybe try to use [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for this?

Comment: And then pass this service to a twig template.

Comment: @Victor please, give me an example code. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a service:

```
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Service/Widget.php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Widget
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getComments()
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request'); // use service_container to access request, doctrine, twig, etc...
    }
}
```

Declare a service:

```
# src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    # ...
    my_widget.class: Acme\HelloBundle\Service\Widget

services:
    my_widget:
        class:     "%my_widget.class%"
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        # scope: container can be omitted as it is the default
```

Use a service in controller:

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;

class BlogController {

    public function getPostAction($id) {
        // get post from db
        $widget = $this->get('my_widget'); // get your widget in controller
        $comments = $widget->getComments(); // do something with comments

        return $this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Blog:index.html.twig',
            array('widget' => $widget) // pass widget to twig
        );
    }
}
```

or in twig, if you pass your service in template like above in `render()` function:

```
#AcmeHelloBundle:Blog:index.html.twig

{{ widget.getComments()|raw }}
```

And usefull to read the docs about [How to work with Scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html)

Comment: And how can get instance of service in Twig ?

Comment: I'm to, but I have not yet found a suggestion how do not use `|raw` filter. If you found - tell me ;)

Comment: For get instance of service in Twig you must to pass it service to twig template, like in my example `return $this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Blog:index.html.twig',
            array('widget' => $widget) // pass widget to twig
        );`

Comment: Yes, but I want to get instance directly in Twig. Let's say I have widget which renders comment icon for news, I have to foreach news in php and then in twig again, I want only once to foreach them in twig. :)

Comment: For only once to foreach them in twig get them in `__construct()` method of your `Widget` service. The `__construct()` method call only once when you first call a service, so you further work with a singleton

Answer (score 2):

I have done it another way. I registered Twig Extension with function {{ comments(object) }}

The function is registered that way

```
'comments' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'comments', array(
        'needs_environment' => true,
        'is_safe' => array('html')
            ))
```

That way I don't need to specify |raw filter.

Comment: What is `object` in `{{ comments(object) }}`?

Comment: Variable ? :D The commented object